# How to count done achievements in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm working on function which will count my achievements which are done by a user and then present that number....
Those achievments are made by google play services.
But I have a problem, because I don't have any errors, but this is not working when I test my app on my phone.

```
  achievementcount = 0;
    if (isConnectedToGoogleServices)
    {
        Social.LoadAchievements(achievements =>
            {
                if (achievements.Length > 0)
                {

                    foreach (IAchievement achievement in achievements)
                    {

                        if (achievement.completed)
                        {
                            achievementcount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    Debug.Log("No achievements returned");
            });
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library to sync up with Google Play's Achievement API?

Comment: I'm using those three:
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

Comment: Are you getting the console message "No achievements returned" or are you just not seeing achievementcount incremented? And maybe silly to ask, you did create the achievements?

Comment: coz of if (isConnectedToGoogleServices) i could not seen any errors in my editor now it tells me this "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in line:

  if (achievements.Length > 0)

Comment: Okay then achievements is null, and accessing .Length is throwing the exception.

Comment: Also i've created the achievements and ShowAchievementsUI(); works perfectly. Any idea why achievments is null?

Comment: Isn't that due to the fact that i'm not connected to google services?

Comment: I don't think google play service returns anything regarding leaderboard or  achievements in unity editor. Did you try in a real device or may be in bluestack?

Comment: @ZayedUpal I've already tested on real device. It seems to not work. (I've installed it through google play)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is correct, but I assume you are setting some text element after the isConnected if.

I tested this and you should make it like:

```
achievementcount = 0;
    if (isConnectedToGoogleServices)
    {
        Social.LoadAchievements(achievements =>
            {
                if (achievements.Length > 0)
                {

                    foreach (IAchievement achievement in achievements)
                    {

                        if (achievement.completed)
                        {
                            achievementcount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    Debug.Log("No achievements returned");

               //*HERE*
            });
    }
```

in *HERE* you should change your achievement count text.

To Debug errors like this you can use: [link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12047)